# How to return Value to Fragment from Dataparser class

Tags: android

I try to pass an `ArrayList<Hashmap<String, String>>` from my Dataparser class to my Fragment. Unfortunately, I don't know how to get the value of die ArrayList.
I created a Dataparser class where I load a json from url.

Here is the code of this class:

```
public class LocDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
private static final String TAG = LocDownloader.class.getSimpleName();
String url = "http://partypeople.bplaced.net/loli.php";
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;


@Override
protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    // Making a request to url and getting response
    HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);


    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONArray contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

            // Getting JSON Array node


            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString("id");
                String name = c.getString("name");
                String street = c.getString("street");
                String postalcode = c.getString("postalcode");
                String entry = c.getString("entry");
                String opening = c.getString("opening");
                String agegroup = c.getString("agegroup");
                String imageurl = c.getString("imageurl");
                String urlbtn = c.getString("urlbtn");
                String lat = c.getString("lat");
                String lng = c.getString("lng");
                String background = c.getString("background");
                String fsk = c.getString("Fsk");
                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                contact.put("id", id);
                contact.put("name", name);
                contact.put("postalcode", postalcode);
                contact.put("entry", entry);
                contact.put("opening", opening);
                contact.put("agegroup", agegroup);
                contact.put("imageurl", imageurl);
                contact.put("urlbtn", urlbtn);
                contact.put("lat", lat);
                contact.put("lng", lng);
                contact.put("background", background);
                contact.put("street", street);
                contact.put("Fsk", fsk);

                contactList.add(contact);
                Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground: " + contactList);
                // adding contact to contact list


            }

        } catch (final JSONException e) {


        }
    } else {


    }
    return contactList;
}
```

}

This class I call in my Fragment

```
public class Qr_Fragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = Qr_Fragment.class.getSimpleName();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> locdata;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.qr, container, false);
    locdata = new ArrayList<>();


        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"hallo"+locdata,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return rootView;
}
```

}

but the problem is I can't return the value of ContactList after calling this class.
How can I return contactlist to my Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Override `onPostExecute` Method of `AsyncTask` which will accept return of `doInBackground`

```
 @Override
    public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data){
        locData = data;
    }
```

**EDIT**

You can create `AsyncTask` as inner class inside your `Fragment` and do operations on `onPostExecute` which will run on `UI Thread`

(or)

create interface and pass it to `AsyncTask` which gets data back to `fragment`

```
public interface DataListener{
 void onData(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data);
}
```

Then pass it as arguments to `AsyncTask`

```
public class LocDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
  private static final String TAG = LocDownloader.class.getSimpleName();
  String url = "http://partypeople.bplaced.net/loli.php";
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
  private DataListener dataListener;
      public LocDownloader(DataListener listener){
          dataListener = listener;
      }
      ... // rest of the code
     @Override
     public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data){
       dataListener.onData(data); // sets the data back
     }  
}
```

Consuming `AsyncTask` in `Fragment`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.qr, container, false);
    locdata = new ArrayList<>();
    new LocDownloader(new DataListener(){
      @Override
      public void onData(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data){
          locData.addAll(data); // <-- Data gets added here
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"hallo"+locdata,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
    }).execute();
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: and how should i call the Parser class to get the value